# Android studio- Tabs- Changing from swipe views to action bar tabs

Tags: structure, project

I am already in the middle of my project and i need to change my tabs from swipe views to action bar tabs without starting a new project. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in activity_main.xml under `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Add the below code in MainActivity.java in `onCreate()`

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

And yeah it should display the action bar tabs!
It worked for me, Hope it helps!